# Зацикливание при вводе символа

Tags: c, матрицы, scanf, goto, stdin

Писал функцию по заполнению матрицы с проверкой, что ввел не символ, а число:

```
int** setMatrix(int graph_size) {
    /*Выделение памяти под матрицу смежности*/
    int** matrix = (int**)malloc(graph_size * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < graph_size; i++) {
        matrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * graph_size);
    }
    /* Ввод матрицы смежности */
enterAgain:
    printf("\nEnter matrix\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < graph_size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < graph_size; j++) {
                int temp;
                //int rc = scanf("%d", &temp);
                if (!scanf("%d", &temp)) {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    goto enterAgain;
                }
                else
                {
                    matrix[i][j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    return matrix;
}
```

Однако, если я ввожу символ, то происходит зацикливание с выводом "Enter matrix". Не знаю в чем проблема.
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вводе не-числа в потоке ввода остаются данные после `scanf()`. Сначала надо от них избавиться:

```
int** setMatrix(int graph_size) {
    char ch;
    /* ... */
                if (!scanf("%d", &temp)) {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    do {
                        ch = getchar();
                    } while ((ch != EOF) && (ch != '\n'));
                    goto enterAgain;
                }
    /* ... */ 
}
```

Comment: https://ideone.com/PFLuIE